# HTML+CSS+Javascript framework for printable HTML forms?

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I need to prepare some forms for a football tournament. Simple stuff: tables and rules and some text labels. At first I launched a DTP app to create a printable PDF form, but then I realized I would rather do the thing in HTML, CSS, and Javascript.

Is there a printable-form-oriented framework that would let me typeset a form, then optionally let the users fill in some text and print the whole thing, client-side?

Please note that I’m not after the regular interactive HTML forms designed to be submitted to some backend service. I want something that emulates the old-school paper forms and, for optional bonus points, would let the users enter some text data before printing.

---

To give an example, a source like this:

```
<h1>Player List</h1>
<div class="field" data-label="Team Name" class="right"></div>
<table data-rows="5">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>number</th>
            <th>name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
 </table>
```

…could be rendered as:

```
PLAYER LIST                         _______________
                                       Team Name

number | name
-------+----------
       |
-------+----------
       |
-------+----------
       |
-------+----------
       |
-------+----------
       |
-------+----------
```

And the fields would be clickable and I could fill in the text before printing. (Again, client-side, no server.)

Comment: When creating the HTML you could use http://www.phpform.org/ and for printing via javascript you could look here: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3471121/Print-a-Web-Page-Using-JavaScript.htm

Comment: Honestly... would be pretty simple to setup a set of classes to throw on your inputs and labels that give them a percentage width of their container.  Then some quick styling for said inputs and labels.  Nothing special needed on the print side of stuff, fill out what you want then go file print and it's all there.  I don't see why you dont just make this yourself rather than use a framework?  Seems like it would take me less time.

Comment: I don’t see why one would need a whole framework just for formatting something that small and simple for print – that’s what CSS media types are for. (And if input fields should turn out as problematic in printing, then one could just add a little JS that turns the input values in other HTML elements, and have that called onclick on a large button `Print this!` and call `window.print()` afterwards to trigger the browser’s print dialog …)

Comment: It’s one of those things that would be sweet if the code already existed and not worth it in case it didn’t. If I had to write the code myself, I would be done much faster in the DTP app. I was just hoping for an existing solution with nice, clean styling (or even themes) and some nice extras like building input-filled tables and so on.

Answer (score 1):

[Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) can help you creating a nicely looking form quickly. 
You can optionally use other frameworks like [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/), [Angular](http://angularjs.org/), [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) or [Ember](http://emberjs.com/) to actually save the data somewhere. But is seems like you don't need it.

Comment: +1 for Bootstrap, but given that the data never goes anywhere, the likes of Backbone, Angular etc. are irrelevant.

Comment: You are absolutely right...I saw 'form' + 'entering data' which triggered something in my mind :)

Comment: Bootstrap is too low-level for what I want. As an example, if I want to have a player table in the form, I have to insert all the rows and inputs myself, instead of just saying “I want an editable table with X rows and such columns here”, or even having some controls to insert rows at run time.

Comment: Sorry...can't think of anything that can help you with that.